# Location of directory using git on ubuntu

Tags: git, github

I started using github on Ubuntu. I use PHP/MySQL.

All my applications are in /var/www directory for development.

Now should I create .git directory in each application in /var/www/, such as /var/www/myapp1/.git ?

Or should I copy each application to /home/MyGit/ and create .git directory here?

How are you doing?

Please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Git to store source code, which *should* be separate from production code. So you should have a `/home/you/src/appname` directory with the source code, which is where you should initialize Git.

When you are happy with an update, check it into Git and copy it to `/var/www/`.

Comment: When I am happy with an update it is in /var/www. So do you mean I need to push to github from /var/www and pull to /home/my/app ?

Comment: I am suggesting you do your work in `/home/...`. Whenever you copy to `/var/www`, also commit your change to Git. Push to Github whenever you feel like it (preferably after cleaning up your history, if it is messy).

Comment: How can I work on home directory? At the moment I can only show localhost in a web browser in /var/www directory apps.

Comment: Generally it is better to work under `home`, as it is usually on a separate partition (safe from system upgrades), and more likely to be backed up (not just a bunch of replaceable system files). I was making the (likely incorrect) assumption that you were serving a production web site from `/var/www`, which makes that a bad place to do development. Now that I understand you are not doing that, I suggest doing your work in `/home` and updating your web server configuration to point there, as `/home` is generally a safer development area (see @Micah's answer).

Comment: You'd have to check the documentation; I don't even know which web server you're using. Apache, for example, requires a pretty simple update to a configuration file under `/etc/apache2/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever your preference is.

Personally, I have all of my projects under my home folder and if I do any local testing from /var/www I use a symlink. The reason for this is because my /home directory is mounted on it's own partition and is backed up. So I can re-install Ubunut, wiping out the contents of /var/www, and simply restore my symlinks. My .git repositories are created wherever I have that project within my home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally people have used git to track a single project, so creating a repository for each applications would be the way to go if you like to follow tradition. Unless your entire www folder is an application, I wouldn't make one big git repository.

Comment: I did not mean that I am going to create one .git. I wanted to know how to handle production code and source code in your computer.